# mongodb - how to find latest version document for each id in collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents such as:

```
{ id: 1, version: 1 }, { id: 1, version:2 }, { id: 2, version: 1 }
```

Is it possible to construct a query that gets me the document with greatest version for each id so that the query would return this?

```
[{ id: 1, version: 2}, { id: 1, version: 1 }]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but read the caveat:

```
db.coll.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$groupId", version : { $max : "$version"} } } );
```

I took the liberty of renaming `id` to `groupId`, because I find having an `id` (not a key, not unique) and an `_id` (PK) irritating

### Caveat

Finding the biggest item from a group is a somewhat complex problem, because it requires grouping and sorting within the group - while that's possible using the aggregation framework, it is advisable to avoid this type of read-heavy query on large collections.

Keeping a reference to the most recent version might be a better idea, e.g. by introducing a `groups` collection and keeping a `currentVersion` in there (or a direct `_id` reference to the current version's document). That must be updated on insert, but makes the queries considerably easier.